# Как узнать состояние кнопки (state) CustomTKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Написал код при помощи библиотеки TKinter (2 кнопки, первая - меняет цвет окна на случайный, вторая - выключает первую)

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import *

def random_color():
    root.config(bg=f'#{randint(100, 1000)}')

def disabler():
    if btn1['state'] == tk.DISABLED:
        btn1['state']=tk.NORMAL
    else:
        btn1['state']=tk.DISABLED

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Сменятор цвета')
h = 500
w = 1000
root.geometry(f'{w}x{h}')
root.resizable(False, False)

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='Случайный цвет',
                 command=random_color)

btn2 = tk.Button(root, text='Переключатель',
                 command=disabler)


btn1.pack()
btn2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Хотел перенести это дело на CustomTKinter, но встретился с проблемой - в старой библиотеке я могу обратиться к btn1, как к словарю и изгнать состояние параметра state . В новой я же не могу сделать этого, выдает ошибку при нажатии на переключатель.

```
import customtkinter as tk
from random import *

def random_color():
    root.config(bg=f'#{randint(100, 1000)}')

def disabler():
    if btn1['state'] == tk.DISABLED:
        btn1['state']=tk.NORMAL
    else:
        btn1['state']=tk.DISABLED

root = tk.CTk()
root.title('Сменятор цвета')
h = 500
w = 1000 
root.geometry(f'{w}x{h}')
root.resizable(False, False)

btn1 = tk.CTkButton(root, text='Случайный цвет',
                 command=random_color)

btn2 = tk.CTkButton(root, text='Переключатель',
                 command=disabler)


btn1.pack()
btn2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Не могу понять чем заменить это обращение к словарю и как узнать значение state

Также в библиотеке TKinter можно поменять цвет фона например так: root[‘bg’] = ‘black’, не обращаясь к методу config . Как заменить это в новой библиотеке - не знаю..
Прощу помощи :)

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы узнать можно использовать `.cget`, чтобы задать можно использовать `.configure`. В результате нужно изменить функцию на такую:

```py
def disabler():
    if btn1.cget('state') == tk.DISABLED:
        btn1.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
    else:
        btn1.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
```